# Parse Xml Post Data to Dictionnary

Tags: .net, regex, dictionary, xml-parsing

I have some post that SaleForce is sending to my webservice

```
 [Route("SendPixel")]
 [HttpPost]
 [HttpGet]
 public string SendPixel(HttpRequestMessage request)
 {

      var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      //parse
  }
```

the content:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Body>
    <Notification>
     <sObject xsi:type="sf:Lead" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
         <sf:Email>wow@vova.wow</sf:Email>
         <sf:Phone>1237556969</sf:Phone>
        </sObject>
       </Notification>
      </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to parse it to 
 **

> Dictionary QueryStringData = new Dictionary();

**

That key will be "Email" and value "wow@vova.wow"

```
QueryStringData[Email][wow@vova.wow]
QueryStringData[Phone][1237556969]
```

How can i do it? Regex or there is another way?

In xml you can see that there is always `<sf:` before the key that i need and then value.

Is there a way to parse like this to Dictionary ?

```
<sf:Phone>1237556969</sf:Phone> ==> <sf:KEY>VALUE</sf:KEY>
```

Comment: Check out the `System.Xml` namespace.

Comment: The Xml provided is malformed...please fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job for current format.

```
     Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        string key = "";
                        string value = "";
              string xmlData = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
using (XmlReader readerTest = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlData)))
                    {
                        while (readerTest.Read())
                        {
                            if (readerTest.LocalName.Contains("Notification"))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    readerTest.MoveToContent();
                                    while (readerTest.Read())
                                    {
                                        if (readerTest.Name.Contains("sf"))
                                        {
                                            key = readerTest.LocalName;
                                            value = readerTest.ReadElementContentAsString();
                                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                                            {
                                                _dictionary.Add(key, value);
                                            }


                                        }

                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) { }
                            }
                        }
                        readerTest.Close();
                    }
```